# How write to csv file this data correctly = "type" not """ type """

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried to write this data to csv file but it writes not correctly. I want receive "type" not """type"""

python3, pycharm

```
 import pandas as pd
 import csv

 def main():
    req = pd.read_csv('/Users/user/web/python/Book copy.csv')
    account = 'test'
    transferType = 'Loan'
    comment = "test"

    with open('data2.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['"type"','"currency"','"amount"','"comment"'])

        for i in range(len(req)):
            currency = req['Currency'].values[i]
            reqAmount = req['Request'].values[i]
            r = round(reqAmount, -1)
            data = [transferType, account, currency, r, comment]
            writer.writerow(data)

    print("DONE")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

"""type"""

Comment: Please be precise with your indentation when posting Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your header row needs to be quoted but the issue is that `"` is the default quote character and is being escaped, you need to change it to something else if you really want quoted headers

```
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='$')
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Maybe it was easy  and stupid question but ive been learnin python 
 for only few weeks (

Answer (score 1):

On top of what the @Iain Shelvington mentioned about escaping the `"`, I would also change your delimeter to `','` if you want a spreadsheet program like Excel to read the output on opening as a formatted spreadsheet. Moreover, if you don't want the " characters to appear in the column headers of the csv then remove them from the list as such:

```
writer.writerow(['type','currency','amount','comment'])
```